# Trying to get certain registry keys doesn't work c#

Tags: c#, registry

I'm writing some code in C# I sued to use in VBScript which gets some of the windows installation data with the intention of emailing me this information.  I need to get Product versions, keys etc for windows and teamviewer.  Most of this works but some of the product key / digitalproductkey info doesnt.  So for instance

```
string releaseId = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ReleaseId", "").ToString();
```

works but

```
string ProductID = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "ProductId", "").ToString();}
```

doesnt

Comment: maybe you need to run it as an administrator

Comment: Are you accessing the registry as 32-bit or 64-bit? There are different registries depending on what your program is compiled as.